# error in long exposure time

Tags: camera, sony

when taking a shot using a long shutter speed >15 seg an error message is returned instead of the result containing the pocture address.The error message is "error": [40403, "Long Shooting"] .
the camera is a nex-6  the api realease v = 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Please use getAvailableShutterSpeed method to get current possible values.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team

Answer (score 0):

See the special note in the API documentation in the "actTakePicture" section. For very long exposure times it will return error code 40403 in which case you can poll the camera using the "awaitTakePicture" method. The camera will continue to return 40403 when queried with "awaitTakePicture" until it's finished capturing, and then it will return the address of the postview image.